# Why DMA can't approach global variable (STM32)?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, arm, memory, dma

I test memory to memory DMA with my STM32H750VBT.
I study with following this link.   [enter link description here](https://www.codeinsideout.com/blog/stm32/dma/)

According this link, source is inside flash and destination is inside SRAM.
I test that link and it work well.

I test if source is global variable DMA start function return HAL_OK but,
DMA polling function failed. DMA action didn't execute.

That situation happened same when LTDC approach global variable.

I think AHB or APB1 like that stuff can't access global variable.

But I don't know where to find it.

And I don't know it happen no matter any STM32 familys.

Give me some clues everybody!

```
    #define BUFFER_LEN    1024
    uint16_t index = 0;
    uint8_t dst_buffer[BUFFER_LEN] = {0};
    uint8_t* src_buffer = 0x24000000;
```

//dst_buffer define at global variable area.

```
      //fill memory.
      for(index = 0;index < BUFFER_LEN; index++)
      {
          src_buffer[index] = index & 0Xff;
      }
      //DMA START.
      result = HAL_DMA_Start(&hdma_memtomem_dma2_stream0, (uint32_t)src_buffer, (uint32_t)dst_buffer, BUFFER_LEN);
      //Polling MCU until DMA done.
      result = HAL_DMA_PollForTransfer(&hdma_memtomem_dma2_stream0, HAL_DMA_FULL_TRANSFER, BUFFER_LEN);
```

And STM32H750VBT memory area is here
[image]

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue. You need to invalidate any cache entries for that memory area. How to do this? Not sure on the stm32, but a quick Google should find the solution as it is a common problem. Usually there are CMSIS functions for this.

Comment: Generally DMA buffers should be `volatile` qualified to prevent incorrect optimizations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your compiler/linker is placing your `dst_buffer` into the `RAM` section at 0x20000000.
If you check the STM32H7 family reference manual or the datasheet for the STM32H750 device, you'll find that the 128k of RAM at 0x20000000 is located in the `DTCM` block.
This block is one of 2 "tightly coupled memory" blocks (the other one being the 64k `ITCM` block at 0x00000000).
These 2 RAM blocks can be accessed by the microcontroller core faster than the other RAM blocks on the AXI bus, but these blocks *cannot be accessed by the standard DMA peripheral*.

Probably the simplest solution to this problem would be for you to tell your compiler/linker to locate your `dst_buffer` in one of the other memory blocks (using something like an `__attribute__((section ...))` or `#pragma section ...` compiler directive) or to change your linker configuration to locate the `.bss` section over into one of the other RAM_Dx blocks.

Another option might be to use the MDMA peripheral instead of the "plain" DMA, because I think the MDMA is able to access the DTCM block, but I'm not entirely sure.

You're going to encounter this same issue again if you start using one of the "smart" peripherals like USB or Ethernet which have their own built-in DMA functionality to read and write their packet buffers. Just like the "plain" DMA peripheral, these other peripherals are not able to access the DTCM or ITCM blocks.

Comment: How did you know this from the info provided?

Comment: @DKNguyen - because I've spent the last 2 years (on & off) working on a project which uses an STM32H750 device, and way back at the beginning I wasted weeks of my time trying to figure out this same issue :P

Comment: So nothing from the info provided would indicate that. Gotcha. What makes the compiler decide to place a variable in DTCM?

Comment: The linker script that you feed the compiler along with the code does that and we can see in the OP's question that the `RAM` segment is placed at 0x20000000. None of the other segments are used - which means that all the standard C sections (.bss, .data, etc) are all in the `RAM` segment. In this device, putting variables in the DTCM block would tend to give a slight performance boost (because it's "tightly coupled" to the core) over the other RAM blocks out on the AXI bus, so that's probably why most compilers' default linker scripts put them there.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize it would do that by default.

Comment: In a more "simple" micro without multiple blocks of RAM you probably rarely every even have to think about the linker script your compiler uses because everything just works - but it is still there. But this micro has a bunch of separate RAM blocks, and even if you're not trying to DMA anything you'd still need to edit the linker script to tell the compiler to locate some things in specific blocks if you actually need to use all the RAM.